# Can we use conch shell (shankh) during the worship of Lord Shiva?

Tags: shiva, shiva-purana, vedic-rituals, shivadvaita

I know that as per the story (like found in [Shiva Purana: Rudra-saṃhitā: Yuddha-khaṇḍa: Chapter 40](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-english/d/doc226181.html)) of Shankhchud killed by Shiva, it was banned from his worship.

But still I have seen many people, specially in Varanasi's sandhya aarti and in many temples of Lord Shiva from south India, brahmins are using the conch shell frequently.

Comment: I also hv similar Q...As per stories, Tulasi should not be offered to Ganesha but I hv seen in many homes in South India that they put Tulasi plant in Gamla with Ganesha image means continuously offering Tulasi to Ganesha..

Comment: For blowing purpose or for Shankh Puja purpose?

Comment: For the purpose of blowing & pouring water on shivling. @Rickross

Comment: Pouring water with shankha with darbha or saligramw on top of lingamame is allowed but not directly otherwise